# Generating a matlibplot bar chart from two columns of data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to build a vertical bar chart based on the examples provided in [How to plot a very simple bar chart (Python, Matplotlib) using input *.txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617719/how-to-plot-a-very-simple-bar-chart-python-matplotlib-using-input-txt-file) and [pylab_examples example code: barchart_demo.py](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/barchart_demo.html).

```
# a bar chart
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = """100 0.0
      5 500.25
      2 10.0
      4 5.55
      3 950.0
      3 300.25"""

counts = []
values = []

for line in data.split("\n"):
    x, y = line.split()
    values = x
    counts = y

plt.bar(counts, values)

plt.show()
```

Current I am receiving the following error: `AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 15 or scalar`. I am not sure if the `plt.bar()` function is defined correctly. There may be other issues I have overlooked in trying to replicate the two previously mentioned examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

x, y = line.split() returns a tuple of strings.  I believe you need to convert them to ints and floats.  You also need values.append(x) and values.append(y).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = """100 0.0
      5 500.25
      2 10.0
      4 5.55
      3 950.0
      3 300.25"""

counts = []
values = []

for line in data.split("\n"):
    x, y = line.split()
    values.append(int(x))
    counts.append(float(y))

plt.bar(counts, values)

plt.show()
```

Given the 100 value in the first line (compared to <= 5 for the rest), it makes for a pretty ugly bar chart though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to do something like

```
for line in data.split("\n"):
    x, y = line.split()
    values.append(int(x))
    counts.append(float(y))
```